# why gmtime and localtime give me the same result?

Tags: c++, c

I have following test code to see the difference between gmtime and localtime. But they give me the same result: **UTC:2013-05-02T13:59:58 Local:2013-05-02T13:59:58**

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
tm *pTimeStruct = gmtime(&now);
tm *plocalTimeStruct = localtime(&now);

string timeStr = "";
char timeBuf[64] = {'\0'};

sprintf(timeBuf,"UTC:%-4.4d-%-2.2d-%-2.2dT%-2.2d:%-2.2d:%-2.2d "
    "Local:%-4.4d-%-2.2d-%-2.2dT%-2.2d:%-2.2d:%-2.2d",
    (pTimeStruct->tm_year + 1900),
    (pTimeStruct->tm_mon + 1),
    pTimeStruct->tm_mday,
    pTimeStruct->tm_hour,
    pTimeStruct->tm_min,
    pTimeStruct->tm_sec,
    (plocalTimeStruct->tm_year + 1900),
    (plocalTimeStruct->tm_mon + 1),
    plocalTimeStruct->tm_mday,
    plocalTimeStruct->tm_hour,
    plocalTimeStruct->tm_min,
    plocalTimeStruct->tm_sec);

timeStr += timeBuf;
cout << timeStr << endl;
```

EDIT:

I am in Eastern time zone.

EDIT2:

updated code use diff struct, but got the same result:

```
        time_t now;
        time(&now);
        time_t now2;
        time(&now2);
        tm *pTimeStruct = gmtime(&now);
        tm *plocalTimeStruct = localtime(&now2);
```

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: linux machine, fedora

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to copy the values between the calls to `gmtime` and `localtime`:

> The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent  calls to  any  of  the  date  and time functions.

says the man page on my system. That's common behaviour at least on Linux.

Comment: `tm gmtimestruct; memcpy (&gmtimestruct, gmtime(&now), sizeof gmtimestruct);` would behave as expected.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA You still didn't *copy the result* of the call though. You just stored the same pointer in two different places. For example `tm timeStruct = *gmtime(&now);`

Comment: @MarkB: Yes, I think you'll find that `pTimeStruct == plocalTimeStruct`.

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes, I have to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use gmtime_r and localtime_r, which are thread safe and store the data in a user-supplied struct.

```
struct tm *gmtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);
```

Note for Windows users: _gmtime_s and _localtime_s are the Microsoft versions.

```
errno_t _gmtime_s(struct tm* _tm, const __time_t* time);
errno_t _localtime_s(struct tm* _tm, const time_t *time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved it by using memcpy:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);  

tm* gmt = (tm*)malloc(sizeof(tm));
memcpy(gmt, gmtime(&t), sizeof(tm));

tm* loc = localtime(&t);

cout << asctime(gmt) << endl;
cout << asctime(loc) << endl;   

free(gmt);
```

Comment: You should have used assignment. This is C++, not C.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem and solved it by changing

```
tm* gmt=gmtime(&tnow);
```

to

```
#define gmt gmtime(&tnow)
```

Comment: Poor solution. You keep calling `gmtime()` every time you refer to `gmt`, and macros that resolve to function calls should be defined to look like function calls themselves: `#define gmt() ...` so the programmer is aware of it.

Comment: its a fast solution not perfect I agree