# Why are gmtime_r and localtime_r returning same time?

Tags: c, linux

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)

{

    time_t t, nt;  /* seconds time holder */
    struct tm gmt; /* time structure gmt */
    struct tm lcl; /* local time structure */

    t = time(NULL); /* get seconds time */
    gmtime_r(&t, &gmt); /* get gmt */
    localtime_r(&t, &lcl); /* get local */

    printf("gmt hour: %d local hour: %d\n", gmt.tm_hour, lcl.tm_hour);

}
```

The run is:

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ gcc -o test test.c
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ./test
gmt hour: 20 local hour: 20
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ date
Sat 17 Jul 2021 08:28:43 PM PST
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

The answers I have found so far talk about the use of localtime() (not localtime_r), or not having the timezone set, but you can see from above that was done.

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks,

Scott Franco
San Jose, CA

Ok, playing with the date command:

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ date
Sat 17 Jul 2021 08:28:43 PM PST
```

Is wrong, the time is 1:38pm (13:38), and the clock on the desktop shows the same. Trying to fix that:

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ hwclock -r
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --verbose option to see the details of our search for an access method.
Sat 17 Jul 2021 01:38:00 PM PST
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ sudo date -s "july 17 2021 13:38"
Sat 17 Jul 2021 01:38:00 PM PST
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ date
Sat 17 Jul 2021 08:38:42 PM PST
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

oooooooo ok. Humm...

Clearly I am fighting with the time server, but not sure what is going on.

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ timedatectl
               Local time: Sat 2021-07-17 13:46:51 PDT     
           Universal time: Sat 2021-07-17 20:46:51 UTC     
                 RTC time: Sat 2021-07-17 20:46:52         
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
System clock synchronized: no                              
              NTP service: n/a                             
          RTC in local TZ: no                              
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ./test
gmt hour: 20 local hour: 20
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

Requested by Steve:

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/Desktop$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 23 21:41 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/Desktop$ wc /etc/localtime
   8   86 2836 /etc/localtime
```

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ echo $TZ
PST8PDT
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ./test
gmt hour: 21 local hour: 14
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/Desktop$ pa
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ echo $TZ
America/Los_Angeles
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ./test
gmt hour: 21 local hour: 14
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

This addresses the answer given by Steve:

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 23 13:41 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ echo $TZ
America/Los_Angeles
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ./test
gmt hour: 21 local hour: 14
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ export TZ=""
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ echo $TZ

samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ./test
gmt hour: 21 local hour: 21
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

Requested by KamilCuk:

```
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ zdump -v -c 2019,2022 /etc/localtime
/etc/localtime  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
/etc/localtime  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 10 09:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Mar 10 01:59:59 2019 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 10 10:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Mar 10 03:00:00 2019 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  3 08:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Nov  3 01:59:59 2019 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  3 09:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Nov  3 01:00:00 2019 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar  8 09:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Mar  8 01:59:59 2020 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar  8 10:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Mar  8 03:00:00 2020 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  1 08:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Nov  1 01:59:59 2020 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  1 09:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Nov  1 01:00:00 2020 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 14 09:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Mar 14 01:59:59 2021 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 14 10:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Mar 14 03:00:00 2021 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  7 08:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Nov  7 01:59:59 2021 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  7 09:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Nov  7 01:00:00 2021 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/etc/localtime  9223372036854689407 = NULL
/etc/localtime  9223372036854775807 = NULL
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 23 21:41 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$ ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2836 Jan 27 21:32 /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
samiam@samiam-h-pc-2:~/projects/petit_ami$
```

Comment: Can you run `printenv TZ` or `echo $TZ`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why gmtime and localtime give me the same result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344748/why-gmtime-and-localtime-give-me-the-same-result)

Comment: @user2233706 Scott's use of `localtime_r` and `gmtime_r` means he shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Besides checking your `TZ` environment variable, the file `/etc/localtime` may also be relevant.  Can you do `ls -l /etc/localtime` and `wc /etc/localtime`?

Comment: I tried the posted code and it works for me (it gives different results for gmt vs. local, and the local hour was correct).  One thing I can see that isn't right though is `date` showing `PST` as the timezone.  It should show `PDT` since we're on daylight saving time.  For example, I get:  `Sat Jul 17 13:55:39 PDT 2021`

Comment: Steve, TZ was not in the environment. I added it, it made no difference (TZ=PST).

Comment: Steve, see main edit for the results of that.

Comment: @ScottFranco You don't necessarily need `TZ`, but if it is set, it will affect your results.  But the proper setting for the West Coast is either `TZ=PST8PDT` or `TZ=America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: @ScottFranco Thanks for those experiments.  I'm mystified.  The only thing I could think of that would cause your results would be something badly wrong with `/etc/localtime` or `$TZ`, but what you have looks fine.  Very strange.

Comment: As for setting the clock, you need to be `root` to do that.  But if you're just reading the time then `root` isn't needed.

Comment: That TZ=PST8PDT fixes it (see main edit). I'm still mystified, but now I have the results I wanted, thanks. Did you want to put that as an answer so I can mark it as being answered?

Comment: why gmtime and localtime give me the same result? – user2233706 Yes, I looked at that first. The issue there was those functions don't copy the result. I used gmtime_r and localtime_r to avoid that issue. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottFranco Glad to hear it, but this isn't really an answer, it's just a workaround for a *very* strange problem.  There's something wrong with your machine's default timezone setup.  Tom Karzes's observation that we're not currently on PST is relevant.

Comment: Steve, yup, what can I say :-) Its ubuntu 20.04 by the by.

Comment: @ScottFranco I'm writing up an answer, but one more experiment: Try setting `TZ` to `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: Same result, see edit.

Comment: What system are you using? Macos? Linux? What distribution? Could you add maybe like `zdump -v -c 2019,2022 /etc/localtime`? Are you using glibc, if so, which version? Paranoid, does `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles` file exists?

Comment: @ScottFranco Thanks. I'm mystified again.  When you set `TZ` to `America/Los_Angeles`, you ought to get the same results as the default (because you're setting `TZ` to what `/etc/localtime` already points to), but you don't.

Comment: KamilCuk please see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Linux system, there are normally two ways to set the time zone:

1. The file `/etc/localtime` is normally a symbolic link to one of the zoneinfo files from the tz database.  For example, on my local machine (a Mac), it points to `/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/America/New_York`, and on a Debian server I have access to in Seattle, it points to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles`.  In any case, `/etc/localtime` sets the machine's default time zone.
2. The environment variable `$TZ` can be used on a per-process basis to override the system default.  `$TZ` can be used in two different ways: (a) it can contain the name of a file in the tz database, or (b) it can contain a string like `PST8PDT` that specifies the time zone directly.

When you call one of the `localtime` functions, it normally consults `$TZ` or `/etc/localtime` to find the information it needs to convert a UTC time to local time.

You have discovered that explicitly setting your `$TZ` variable fixes your problem.  This suggests there may be something wrong with your system's copy of the tz database.

On your system, in its default mode, and although `/etc/localtime` seems to be pointing to the zonefile for `America/Los_Angeles`, both your test program and the system `date` command are acting like they're on UTC.  Also the system `date` command is wrongly (doubly wrongly) reporting PST, neither the PDT you're on nor the UTC that it's actually reporting the hour of.

And yet when you set `TZ` to `America/Los_Angeles`, it also worked, suggesting that your tz file is fine.

All I can say at this point is that modern Linux distros (Ubuntu in particular) have been radically rewriting things that had been stable for years and that I thought I understood.  I think I heard that `ntpd` had fallen victim to the borglike embrace of `systemd`, so perhaps the tz database has, too, and this is affecting your results in some bizarre way.

Comment: Think I should file an Ubuntu bug?

Comment: @ScottFranco If you have a way to do that, definitely!  Four aspects: (1) `date` command gives wrong hour, (2) `date` command gives "PST", (3) your program gives wrong hour, (4) setting `TZ` (two different ways) works around.

Comment: @ScottFranco The `zdump` output you posted looks fine, and matches (perfectly!) what I see on a system without the problem you're having.  This result argues further against my hypothesis that "there may be something wrong with your system's copy of the tz database".  So I'm still mystified.